# D3 axis incorrect

Tags: d3.js

Adopting [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/line-chart) example, I get an axis that is incorrect. The axis shows labels for 50 000, 00 000, 50 000, etc, but my data is from 0 - 513836. This is what the axis looks like:

[image]

Here's my code and data:

```js
data = [{
  "value": "478176",
  "date": "2020-06-28"
}, {
  "value": "478278",
  "date": "2020-06-29"
}, {
  "value": "478559",
  "date": "2020-06-30"
}, {
  "value": "478559",
  "date": "2020-07-01"
}, {
  "value": "479175",
  "date": "2020-07-02"
}, {
  "value": "479175",
  "date": "2020-07-03"
}, {
  "value": "479175",
  "date": "2020-07-04"
}, {
  "value": "479379",
  "date": "2020-07-05"
}, {
  "value": "479633",
  "date": "2020-07-06"
}, {
  "value": "480010",
  "date": "2020-07-07"
}, {
  "value": "480531",
  "date": "2020-07-08"
}, {
  "value": "480794",
  "date": "2020-07-09"
}, {
  "value": "480794",
  "date": "2020-07-10"
}, {
  "value": "480794",
  "date": "2020-07-11"
}, {
  "value": "480995",
  "date": "2020-07-12"
}, {
  "value": "481161",
  "date": "2020-07-13"
}, {
  "value": "481161",
  "date": "2020-07-14"
}, {
  "value": "481934",
  "date": "2020-07-15"
}, {
  "value": "482218",
  "date": "2020-07-16"
}, {
  "value": "482218",
  "date": "2020-07-17"
}, {
  "value": "482218",
  "date": "2020-07-18"
}, {
  "value": "482851",
  "date": "2020-07-19"
}, {
  "value": "483331",
  "date": "2020-07-20"
}, {
  "value": "484302",
  "date": "2020-07-21"
}, {
  "value": "484569",
  "date": "2020-07-22"
}, {
  "value": "484734",
  "date": "2020-07-23"
}, {
  "value": "484734",
  "date": "2020-07-24"
}, {
  "value": "484734",
  "date": "2020-07-25"
}, {
  "value": "485123",
  "date": "2020-07-26"
}, {
  "value": "485597",
  "date": "2020-07-27"
}, {
  "value": "486763",
  "date": "2020-07-28"
}, {
  "value": "487392",
  "date": "2020-07-29"
}, {
  "value": "487392",
  "date": "2020-07-30"
}, {
  "value": "487392",
  "date": "2020-07-31"
}, {
  "value": "487392",
  "date": "2020-08-01"
}, {
  "value": "487392",
  "date": "2020-08-02"
}, {
  "value": "487909",
  "date": "2020-08-03"
}, {
  "value": "488496",
  "date": "2020-08-04"
}, {
  "value": "488496",
  "date": "2020-08-05"
}, {
  "value": "490538",
  "date": "2020-08-06"
}, {
  "value": "490538",
  "date": "2020-08-07"
}, {
  "value": "490538",
  "date": "2020-08-08"
}, {
  "value": "491490",
  "date": "2020-08-09"
}, {
  "value": "492511",
  "date": "2020-08-10"
}, {
  "value": "494185",
  "date": "2020-08-11"
}, {
  "value": "494730",
  "date": "2020-08-12"
}, {
  "value": "495052",
  "date": "2020-08-14"
}, {
  "value": "495052",
  "date": "2020-08-15"
}, {
  "value": "495610",
  "date": "2020-08-16"
}, {
  "value": "496394",
  "date": "2020-08-17"
}, {
  "value": "496394",
  "date": "2020-08-18"
}, {
  "value": "498006",
  "date": "2020-08-19"
}, {
  "value": "498631",
  "date": "2020-08-20"
}, {
  "value": "498631",
  "date": "2020-08-21"
}, {
  "value": "498631",
  "date": "2020-08-22"
}, {
  "value": "499186",
  "date": "2020-08-23"
}, {
  "value": "499561",
  "date": "2020-08-24"
}, {
  "value": "500491",
  "date": "2020-08-25"
}, {
  "value": "500491",
  "date": "2020-08-26"
}, {
  "value": "501295",
  "date": "2020-08-27"
}, {
  "value": "501295",
  "date": "2020-08-28"
}, {
  "value": "501295",
  "date": "2020-08-29"
}, {
  "value": "501748",
  "date": "2020-08-30"
}, {
  "value": "502284",
  "date": "2020-08-31"
}, {
  "value": "503353",
  "date": "2020-09-01"
}, {
  "value": "503719",
  "date": "2020-09-02"
}, {
  "value": "504046",
  "date": "2020-09-03"
}, {
  "value": "504046",
  "date": "2020-09-04"
}, {
  "value": "504046",
  "date": "2020-09-05"
}, {
  "value": "504204",
  "date": "2020-09-06"
}, {
  "value": "504697",
  "date": "2020-09-07"
}, {
  "value": "505659",
  "date": "2020-09-08"
}, {
  "value": "506346",
  "date": "2020-09-12"
}, {
  "value": "507109",
  "date": "2020-09-14"
}, {
  "value": "508650",
  "date": "2020-09-16"
}, {
  "value": "509708",
  "date": "2020-09-17"
}, {
  "value": "509708",
  "date": "2020-09-18"
}, {
  "value": "509708",
  "date": "2020-09-19"
}, {
  "value": "510154",
  "date": "2020-09-20"
}, {
  "value": "510226",
  "date": "2020-09-21"
}, {
  "value": "511136",
  "date": "2020-09-22"
}, {
  "value": "511252",
  "date": "2020-09-23"
}, {
  "value": "511253",
  "date": "2020-09-24"
}, {
  "value": "511253",
  "date": "2020-09-25"
}, {
  "value": "511253",
  "date": "2020-09-26"
}, {
  "value": "511363",
  "date": "2020-09-27"
}, {
  "value": "511467",
  "date": "2020-09-28"
}, {
  "value": "511467",
  "date": "2020-09-29"
}, {
  "value": "512016",
  "date": "2020-09-30"
}, {
  "value": "512016",
  "date": "2020-10-01"
}, {
  "value": "512016",
  "date": "2020-10-02"
}, {
  "value": "512016",
  "date": "2020-10-03"
}, {
  "value": "512610",
  "date": "2020-10-04"
}, {
  "value": "512889",
  "date": "2020-10-05"
}, {
  "value": "513552",
  "date": "2020-10-06"
}, {
  "value": "513836",
  "date": "2020-10-07"
}];

parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

line = d3.line()
  .defined(d => !isNaN(d.value))
  .x(d => x(parseDate(d.date)))
  .y(d => y(parseInt(d.value)));

margin = ({
  top: 20,
  right: 30,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 40
});
height = 500;
width = 500;

x = d3.scaleUtc()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => parseDate(d.date)))
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right]);

y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => parseInt(d.value))]).nice()
  .range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

xAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`)
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(width / 80).tickSizeOuter(0));

yAxis = g => g
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
  .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  //.attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%");

svg.append("g")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .call(yAxis);

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
  .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
  .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're margin isn't wide enough to accommodate all the digits for the axis ticks - try a left margin of 60 and you should see the proper ticks. For reference, your question originally flagged this as a scale issue, in terms of sourcing the issue, that the line is drawn as expected should indicate a successful use of the scale. In the browser, you can inspect the elements in the SVG to see if the text value of the ticks, if they don't correspond to what you see, chances are you have a placement issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didnt notice that it was a margin  problem.