# How to adjust linear axis on D3 line graph to accommodate larger domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a line chart that has large variance in the data using D3 (using a linear scale). [Here's a working project I have going on VizHub (Js code below).](https://vizhub.com/AWkmonroe/c1d7f271f580465aa841f8004ee27dd6?edit=files&file=index.js) I've been trying to follow [this tutorial.](https://datawanderings.com/2019/11/01/tutorial-making-an-interactive-line-chart-in-d3-js-v-5/)
When using my own data (within "lineGraph.csv" on VizHub), I'm running into issues visualizing the data on the y-axis (getting zeroes). After tweaking the yScale, I think it's because there's too large of a variance in the yScale to show cleanly on the axis.

My expected output is something like this line graph from CodePen -  https://codepen.io/zakariachowdhury/pen/JEmjwq?editors=0010. On that graph I am able to edit the values there and see the y-axis adjust, no matter how high the value.

```js
const width = 960;
const height = 400;
const margin = 50;
const padding = 0;
const adj = 30;

const svg = d3
  .select('div#container')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin meet')
  .attr('viewBox', `-${adj} -${adj} ${width + adj * 3} ${height + adj * 3}`)
  // .attr("width", (width+margin)+"px")
  // .attr("height", (height+margin)+"px")
  .style('padding', padding)
  .style('margin', margin)
  .classed('svg-content', true);

const timeConv = d3.timeParse('%d-%b-%Y');
const dataset = d3.csv('lineGraph.csv');
dataset.then(function(data) {
  const slices = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: timeConv(d.date),
          measurement: +d[id],
        };
      }),
    };
  });

  console.log('Column headers', data.columns);
  console.log('Column headers without date', data.columns.slice(1));
  // returns the sliced dataset
  console.log('Slices', slices);
  // returns the first slice
  console.log('First slice', slices[0]);
  // returns the array in the first slice
  console.log('A array', slices[0].values);
  // returns the date of the first row in the first slice
  console.log('Date element', slices[0].values[0].date);
  // returns the array's length
  console.log('Array length', slices[0].values.length);

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){
    return timeConv(d.date)}));

yScale.domain([(0), d3.max(slices, function(c) {
    return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.measurement + 4 ; });
        })
    ])

  const yaxis = d3
    .axisLeft()
    .ticks(slices[0].values.length)
    .scale(yScale);

  const xaxis = d3
    .axisBottom()
    .ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))
    .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%b %d'))
    .scale(xScale);

  const line = d3
    .line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return xScale(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return yScale(d.measurement);
    });

  let id = 0;
  const ids = function() {
    return `line-${id++}`;
  };

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(xaxis);

  svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(yaxis)
    .append('text')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
    .attr('dy', '.75em')
    .attr('y', 6)
    .style('text-anchor', 'end')
    .text('# Premises');

  const lines = svg
    .selectAll('lines')
    .data(slices)
    .enter()
    .append('g');

  lines
    .append('path')
    .attr('class', ids)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    });

  lines
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'serie_label')
    .datum(function(d) {
      return {
        id: d.id,
        value: d.values[d.values.length - 1],
      };
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
      return `translate(${xScale(d.value.date) +
        10},${yScale(d.value.measurement) + 5})`;
    })
    .attr('x', 5)
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });
});
```

Comment: Feels like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64287777/7106086) question - if you inspect the zeros you are getting, do you see the full number? If so, just increase your margin.